# How to add back disabled audio devices?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, digital-audio, spdif

I have two sound output devices, a soundbar using digital optical S/PDIF (motherboard rear panel) and a pair of headphones using a 3.5mm phonejack.

I was recently having trouble getting a piece of software to output to the headphones instead of the speaker.  But when I tried disabling my soundbar from *Control Panel* > *Sound* > *Playback* (also accessable from the tray icon) it completely removed the S/PDIF HD digital audio device from the list of playback devices and now my computer no longer recognizes it at all.

I have looked all through the Sound menu in Control Panel, the Realtek HD Audio Manager, and device manager and I can't find any sign of a connected digital audio device anywhere.  Realtek Manager recognizes my optical port but doesn't show that anything is plugged in.

So how can I re-add an audio device I have disabled?

Comment: In device manager, in the menu there is an option to 'scan for new devices', that should find it.

Comment: @Aganju I already tried that and it didn't work.  As it turns out Windows hides disabled audio devices so you have to set it to show them in order to re-enable it.

Answer (score 2):

By default it seems that control panel hides disabled audio devices in the Sound menu.  To fix this right-click anywhere in the list of devices and choose *Show Disconnected Devices*

[image]

Now the disabled devices should show up allowing you to right-click and enable them.

Comment: Of course this was in the first article I read *after* posting this question, and none of the dozen I read beforehand.